# How use an svg as a mouse cursor in JS or CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I'm having troubles while trying to make a svg being the cursor while hovering an image.
Here's the example:

```
<div class="main">
 <div class="image1"></div>
 <div class="image2"></div>
 <div class="image3"></div>
<svg class="arrowWrapper" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 270.7 166.49" xml:space="preserve"><g><defs><rect id="SVGID_1_" width="270.7" height="166.49"/></defs><clipPath id="SVGID_2_"><use xlink:href="#SVGID_1_"  style="overflow:visible;"/></clipPath><path style="clip-path:url(#SVGID_2_);fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:3.401;stroke-miterlimit:10;" d="M1.2,83.67 L83.67,1.2 M1.2,82.82l82.46,82.47 M270.7,82.82H2.05"/></g>
</svg>
</div>
```

So when I hover the mouse-pointer over an image, I'd like the svg arrow to appear and follow the mouse-pointer (or just replace the mouse-pointer) until I leave the image.

Comment: Try this rule : `cursor: url(your-path/my-cursor.svg), auto;`

Comment: it doesn't work. I read that the cursor has to be 128x128 or less, is that right?

Comment: That´s right! Serious? You really want a cursor with size more than 128x128? Just make the svg max 128 and you are in your way.

Comment: It's not for me...

Answer (score 0):

you can add cursor on hover like the code below on each of the images and I am pretty sure that the recommended format for image you want to put is png because I had a same problem for my website and I couldn't add an SVG as the cursor

```css
.image1 .image2 .image3:hover{
    cursor: url('image path to your cursor'), auto ;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
 <div class="image1"></div>
 <div class="image2"></div>
 <div class="image3"></div>
</div>
```